# Confused with the use of the phrases

Tags: grammaticality

I am confused with the use of the following phrases. Which usage is correct?

> won in the semi-final/
>   won the semi-final

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and pretty much interchangeable. The emphasis is slightly different.  "Won in the semi-final" emphasizes the game, what strategy they used, who they played against, etc. "Won the semi-final" emphasizes the game's result.